# Reset input field's value with a ref?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a reference (created with `useRef()` ) that points to an input field,
but when the user presses on "space" once, i get the following in my ref:

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="search" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" placeholder="Unit" title=" " value=" ">
```

Which means that the input field's placeholder doesn't show..

How can i detect if there's just one space entered, and if there is, reset the field to the following? (so that the placeholder shows)

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="search" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" placeholder="Unit" title value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. prevent user from entering a whitespace and the beginning of the input.

```
value={value.replace(/^\s+/, '')}

'  some text' --> 'some text'
' '           --> ''
```